# WSO2 data service (DS) in ESB 4.0.3 returns wrong fault message

Tags: macos, wso2, wso2-data-services-server, wso2-esb

I work at Apple and we are working on the prototype using WSO2 ESB with Data Services Feature. I am using *WSO2 ESB 4.0.3* with *DSS* feature. I have deployed data service and calling the data service from proxy service in ESB. I am using *MAC OS X 10.7.4* and java version details are as below.

java version "1.6.0_31"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_31-b04-415-11M3635)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.6-b01-415, mixed mode)

My DS service is expecting certain parameter say parameter A and I do not pass that this parameter in the Input XML I see following error on the WSO2 ESB console.

```
[2012-06-07 09:49:11,348] ERROR - DataService DS Fault Message: Error in 'CallQuery.extractParams', cannot find parameter with type:query-param name:Hw_Serial_Nr
DS Code: INCOMPATIBLE_PARAMETERS_ERROR
Source Data Service:-
Name: OWCHECK
Location: /TQS_OWCHECK.dbs
Description: N/A
Default Namespace: http://ws.wso2.org/dataservice
Current Request Name: OWCHECK_OP
Current Params: {COUNTRYORIGIN=US, SUBDT=20090428}

DS Fault Message: Error in 'CallQuery.extractParams', cannot find parameter with type:query-param name:Hw_Serial_Nr
DS Code: INCOMPATIBLE_PARAMETERS_ERROR
Source Data Service:-
Name: OWCHECK
Location: /TQS_OWCHECK.dbs
Description: N/A
Default Namespace: http://ws.wso2.org/dataservice
Current Request Name: OWCHECK_OP
Current Params: {COUNTRYORIGIN=US, SUBDT=20090428}

    at org.wso2.carbon.dataservices.core.engine.CallQuery.extractParams(CallQuery.java:214)
    at org.wso2.carbon.dataservices.core.engine.CallQuery.execute(CallQuery.java:183)
    at org.wso2.carbon.dataservices.core.engine.CallQueryGroup.execute(CallQueryGroup.java:110)
    at org.wso2.carbon.dataservices.core.description.operation.Operation.execute(Operation.java:71)
    at org.wso2.carbon.dataservices.core.engine.DataService.invoke(DataService.java:592)
    at org.wso2.carbon.dataservices.core.engine.DSOMDataSource.execute(DSOMDataSource.java:99)
    at org.wso2.carbon.dataservices.core.engine.DSOMDataSource.serialize(DSOMDataSource.java:110)
    at org.wso2.carbon.dataservices.core.engine.DSOMDataSource.getReader(DSOMDataSource.java:116)
    at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.llom.OMSourcedElementImpl.getDirectReader(OMSourcedElementImpl.java:225)
    at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.llom.OMSourcedElementImpl.forceExpand(OMSourcedElementImpl.java:254)
    at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.llom.OMSourcedElementImpl.getFirstOMChild(OMSourcedElementImpl.java:867)
    at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.OMNavigator._getFirstChild(OMNavigator.java:196)
    at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.OMNavigator.updateNextNode(OMNavigator.java:140)
    at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.OMNavigator.getNext(OMNavigator.java:112)
    at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.SwitchingWrapper.updateNextNode(SwitchingWrapper.java:1113)
    at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.SwitchingWrapper.updateLastNode(SwitchingWrapper.java:1104)
    at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.SwitchingWrapper.next(SwitchingWrapper.java:1041)
    at javax.xml.stream.util.StreamReaderDelegate.next(StreamReaderDelegate.java:47)
    at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.builder.StAXOMBuilder.parserNext(StAXOMBuilder.java:681)
    at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.builder.StAXOMBuilder.next(StAXOMBuilder.java:214)
    at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.llom.OMSerializableImpl.build(OMSerializableImpl.java:78)
    at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.llom.OMElementImpl.build(OMElementImpl.java:722)
    at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.llom.OMElementImpl.cloneOMElement(OMElementImpl.java:1065)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tracer.module.handler.AbstractTracingHandler.storeMessage(AbstractTracingHandler.java:81)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tracer.module.handler.TracingMessageOutObservationHandler.invoke(TracingMessageOutObservationHandler.java:94)
    at org.apache.axis2.engine.Phase.invokeHandler(Phase.java:340)
    at org.apache.axis2.engine.Phase.invoke(Phase.java:313)
    at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.invoke(AxisEngine.java:262)
    at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.send(AxisEngine.java:427)
    at org.apache.axis2.receivers.AbstractInOutSyncMessageReceiver.invokeBusinessLogic(AbstractInOutSyncMessageReceiver.java:45)
    at org.apache.axis2.receivers.AbstractMessageReceiver.receive(AbstractMessageReceiver.java:110)
    at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.receive(AxisEngine.java:181)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.HTTPTransportUtils.processHTTPPostRequest(HTTPTransportUtils.java:172)
    at org.apache.synapse.transport.nhttp.ServerWorker.processEntityEnclosingMethod(ServerWorker.java:409)
    at org.apache.synapse.transport.nhttp.ServerWorker.run(ServerWorker.java:261)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.base.threads.NativeWorkerPool$1.run(NativeWorkerPool.java:173)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:680)
[2012-06-07 09:49:11,352] ERROR - OMSourcedElementImpl Could not get parser from data source for element {http://ws.wso2.org/dataservice}EVENT
javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: DS Fault Message: Error in 'CallQuery.extractParams', cannot find parameter with type:query-param name:Hw_Serial_Nr
DS Code: INCOMPATIBLE_PARAMETERS_ERROR
Source Data Service:-
Name: OWCHECK
Location: /TQS_OWCHECK.dbs
Description: N/A
Default Namespace: http://ws.wso2.org/dataservice
Current Request Name: OWCHECK_OP
Current Params: {COUNTRYORIGIN=US, SUBDT=20090428}

    at org.wso2.carbon.dataservices.core.engine.DSOMDataSource.execute(DSOMDataSource.java:105)
    at org.wso2.carbon.dataservices.core.engine.DSOMDataSource.serialize(DSOMDataSource.java:110)
    at org.wso2.carbon.dataservices.core.engine.DSOMDataSource.getReader(DSOMDataSource.java:116)
    at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.llom.OMSourcedElementImpl.getDirectReader(OMSourcedElementImpl.java:225)
    at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.llom.OMSourcedElementImpl.forceExpand(OMSourcedElementImpl.java:254)
    at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.llom.OMSourcedElementImpl.getFirstOMChild(OMSourcedElementImpl.java:867)
    at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.OMNavigator._getFirstChild(OMNavigator.java:196)
    at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.OMNavigator.updateNextNode(OMNavigator.java:140)
    at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.OMNavigator.getNext(OMNavigator.java:112)
    at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.SwitchingWrapper.updateNextNode(SwitchingWrapper.java:1113)
    at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.SwitchingWrapper.updateLastNode(SwitchingWrapper.java:1104)
    at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.SwitchingWrapper.next(SwitchingWrapper.java:1041)
    at javax.xml.stream.util.StreamReaderDelegate.next(StreamReaderDelegate.java:47)
    at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.builder.StAXOMBuilder.parserNext(StAXOMBuilder.java:681)
    at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.builder.StAXOMBuilder.next(StAXOMBuilder.java:214)
    at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.llom.OMSerializableImpl.build(OMSerializableImpl.java:78)
    at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.llom.OMElementImpl.build(OMElementImpl.java:722)
    at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.llom.OMElementImpl.cloneOMElement(OMElementImpl.java:1065)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tracer.module.handler.AbstractTracingHandler.storeMessage(AbstractTracingHandler.java:81)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tracer.module.handler.TracingMessageOutObservationHandler.invoke(TracingMessageOutObservationHandler.java:94)
    at org.apache.axis2.engine.Phase.invokeHandler(Phase.java:340)
    at org.apache.axis2.engine.Phase.invoke(Phase.java:313)
    at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.invoke(AxisEngine.java:262)
    at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.send(AxisEngine.java:427)
    at org.apache.axis2.receivers.AbstractInOutSyncMessageReceiver.invokeBusinessLogic(AbstractInOutSyncMessageReceiver.java:45)
    at org.apache.axis2.receivers.AbstractMessageReceiver.receive(AbstractMessageReceiver.java:110)
    at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.receive(AxisEngine.java:181)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.HTTPTransportUtils.processHTTPPostRequest(HTTPTransportUtils.java:172)
    at org.apache.synapse.transport.nhttp.ServerWorker.processEntityEnclosingMethod(ServerWorker.java:409)
    at org.apache.synapse.transport.nhttp.ServerWorker.run(ServerWorker.java:261)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.base.threads.NativeWorkerPool$1.run(NativeWorkerPool.java:173)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:680)
[2012-06-07 09:49:11,355] ERROR - ServerWorker Error processing POST request 
org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException
    at org.apache.axis2.AxisFault.makeFault(AxisFault.java:430)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.HTTPTransportUtils.processHTTPPostRequest(HTTPTransportUtils.java:180)
    at org.apache.synapse.transport.nhttp.ServerWorker.processEntityEnclosingMethod(ServerWorker.java:409)
    at org.apache.synapse.transport.nhttp.ServerWorker.run(ServerWorker.java:261)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.base.threads.NativeWorkerPool$1.run(NativeWorkerPool.java:173)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:680)
Caused by: org.apache.axiom.om.OMException: javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException
    at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.builder.StAXOMBuilder.next(StAXOMBuilder.java:296)
    at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.llom.OMSerializableImpl.build(OMSerializableImpl.java:78)
    at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.llom.OMElementImpl.build(OMElementImpl.java:722)
    at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.llom.OMElementImpl.cloneOMElement(OMElementImpl.java:1065)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tracer.module.handler.AbstractTracingHandler.storeMessage(AbstractTracingHandler.java:81)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tracer.module.handler.TracingMessageOutObservationHandler.invoke(TracingMessageOutObservationHandler.java:94)
    at org.apache.axis2.engine.Phase.invokeHandler(Phase.java:340)
    at org.apache.axis2.engine.Phase.invoke(Phase.java:313)
    at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.invoke(AxisEngine.java:262)
    at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.send(AxisEngine.java:427)
    at org.apache.axis2.receivers.AbstractInOutSyncMessageReceiver.invokeBusinessLogic(AbstractInOutSyncMessageReceiver.java:45)
    at org.apache.axis2.receivers.AbstractMessageReceiver.receive(AbstractMessageReceiver.java:110)
    at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.receive(AxisEngine.java:181)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.HTTPTransportUtils.processHTTPPostRequest(HTTPTransportUtils.java:172)
    ... 6 more
Caused by: javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException
    at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.SwitchingWrapper.updateLastNode(SwitchingWrapper.java:1106)
    at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.SwitchingWrapper.next(SwitchingWrapper.java:1041)
    at javax.xml.stream.util.StreamReaderDelegate.next(StreamReaderDelegate.java:47)
    at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.builder.StAXOMBuilder.parserNext(StAXOMBuilder.java:681)
    at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.builder.StAXOMBuilder.next(StAXOMBuilder.java:214)
    ... 19 more
[2012-06-07 09:49:11,375]  WARN - ClientHandler Received an internal server error : Internal Server Error For : 127.0.0.1:8280 For Request : Axis2Request [Message ID : urn:uuid:55a4d59a-2be2-43ee-99b5-8943b1ff2b91] [Status Completed : true] [Status SendingCompleted : true]
```

How ever the fault message it returned to the proxy service is as below

```
2012-06-07 09:49:11,081 [-] [HttpServerWorker-1] TRACE OWCHECK_RPOXY To: /services/OWCHECK_RPOXY.OWCHECK_RPOXYHttpSoap12Endpoint, WSAction: urn:mediate, SOAPAction: urn:mediate, MessageID: urn:uuid:1f8cb9bf-ab10-40a4-b75d-6b3d4805322c, Direction: request, Envelope: <?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?><soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope"><soapenv:Body><OWCHECK_OP spec="IDL:com/apple/vitria/idl/sapamr_rfcevents/RfcCallEvents:1.0#Z_WARR_VALIDATION_GROUP"><TAB_SERNHDR><SERIALNR>YM6191TJSCH</SERIALNR><SUBDT>20090428</SUBDT><COUNTRYORIGIN>US</COUNTRYORIGIN></TAB_SERNHDR></OWCHECK_OP></soapenv:Body></soapenv:Envelope>
2012-06-07 09:49:11,398 [-] [HttpClientWorker-1] TRACE OWCHECK_RPOXY To: http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing/anonymous, WSAction: , SOAPAction: , MessageID: urn:uuid:55a4d59a-2be2-43ee-99b5-8943b1ff2b91, Direction: response, MESSAGE = In-to-OutSequence !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!, Envelope: <?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?><soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope"><soapenv:Body><soapenv:Fault><soapenv:Code><soapenv:Value>soapenv:Receiver</soapenv:Value></soapenv:Code><soapenv:Reason><soapenv:Text xml:lang="en-US">javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException</soapenv:Text></soapenv:Reason><soapenv:Detail><Exception>org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException
    at org.apache.axis2.AxisFault.makeFault(AxisFault.java:430)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.HTTPTransportUtils.processHTTPPostRequest(HTTPTransportUtils.java:180)
    at org.apache.synapse.transport.nhttp.ServerWorker.processEntityEnclosingMethod(ServerWorker.java:409)
    at org.apache.synapse.transport.nhttp.ServerWorker.run(ServerWorker.java:261)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.base.threads.NativeWorkerPool$1.run(NativeWorkerPool.java:173)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:680)
Caused by: org.apache.axiom.om.OMException: javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException
    at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.builder.StAXOMBuilder.next(StAXOMBuilder.java:296)
    at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.llom.OMSerializableImpl.build(OMSerializableImpl.java:78)
    at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.llom.OMElementImpl.build(OMElementImpl.java:722)
    at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.llom.OMElementImpl.cloneOMElement(OMElementImpl.java:1065)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tracer.module.handler.AbstractTracingHandler.storeMessage(AbstractTracingHandler.java:81)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tracer.module.handler.TracingMessageOutObservationHandler.invoke(TracingMessageOutObservationHandler.java:94)
    at org.apache.axis2.engine.Phase.invokeHandler(Phase.java:340)
    at org.apache.axis2.engine.Phase.invoke(Phase.java:313)
    at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.invoke(AxisEngine.java:262)
    at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.send(AxisEngine.java:427)
    at org.apache.axis2.receivers.AbstractInOutSyncMessageReceiver.invokeBusinessLogic(AbstractInOutSyncMessageReceiver.java:45)
    at org.apache.axis2.receivers.AbstractMessageReceiver.receive(AbstractMessageReceiver.java:110)
    at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.receive(AxisEngine.java:181)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.HTTPTransportUtils.processHTTPPostRequest(HTTPTransportUtils.java:172)
    ... 6 more
Caused by: javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException
    at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.SwitchingWrapper.updateLastNode(SwitchingWrapper.java:1106)
    at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.SwitchingWrapper.next(SwitchingWrapper.java:1041)
    at javax.xml.stream.util.StreamReaderDelegate.next(StreamReaderDelegate.java:47)
    at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.builder.StAXOMBuilder.parserNext(StAXOMBuilder.java:681)
    at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.builder.StAXOMBuilder.next(StAXOMBuilder.java:214)
    ... 19 more
</Exception></soapenv:Detail></soapenv:Fault></soapenv:Body></soapenv:Envelope>
```

Looking at the SOAP fault I have to return the error message to client but even thought the correct error message must "Parameter Missing" SOAP fault's reason text is "`javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException`"

Is there any thing wrong I am doing or is it BUG in DSS?

Answer (score 0):

By looking at the stacktrace, I can see that you've enabled the SOAP tracer in invoking the service, disable the SOAP tracer and you should get the proper fault message.

Cheers,
Anjana.

Answer (score 0):

As error message explains itself, it is expecting input parameters, which is not coming int the request. It can be fixed by two ways:

1. Passing empty tag from ESB without value.
2. Set default value in DSS.

First option works with all versions, here is the example for setting default value.

```
<payloadFactory media-type="xml">
    <format>
        <ds:DATA_SERVICE_REQUST xmlns:ds="http://ws.wso2.org/dataservice">
            <ds:INPUT_PARAM_1>$1</ds:INPUT_PARAM_1>
        </ds:DATA_SERVICE_REQUST>
    </format>
    <args>
        <arg xmlns:ds="http://ws.wso2.org/dataservice" evaluator="xml" expression="get-property('INPUT_PARAMETER')"/>
    </args>
</payloadFactory>
<call>
    <endpoint>
        <address uri="DSS_END_POINT"/>
   </endpoint>
</call>
```

For 2nd option, please check your DSS version if this supports null values

Latest Version of DSS Supports default parameter values in the query param list.
Could you please give a try by adding `defaultValue="#{NULL}"` in query param list in your data service (dbs) file?

```
<query id="QUERY-ID" useConfig="DATA-SOURCE-ID">
    <sql>-------------SQL QUERY HERE -----</sql>
    <result ----------- >
        <element ------------ />  
    </result>
    <param defaultValue="#{NULL}" name="PARAM-NAME" ordinal="1" sqlType="INTEGER"/>
</query>
```

If this issue is still not resolved then it would be good if you can provide your API details.